# how to get selected value inside column field in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i have level_name field in my table then inside got [level1,level2,level3,level4,level5], now i want to get level1 to level3 only how do i construct it inside my controller

**Controller:**

```
  $levels=Level::orderBy('id','asc')->where(['level_name'=>[level1,level2,level3]])->get();
    return view('markbook.show_level',compact('levels'));
```

Comment: whereIn('level_name',  [level1, level3])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `whereIn` in place of `where`

```
$levels = Level::orderBy('id','asc')->whereIn('level_name', [level1,level2,level3])->get();
```